# Getting rows from pandas dataframe that match at least n conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want to extract the rows that match certain criteria.
In simple cases, I would make boolean 'masks' as shown below, and combine those with `&` and `|`.

```
import pandas as pd

foo = {
  "A": [1,2,3,4],
  "B": [1,2,3,5],
  "C": [2,4,6,8],
  "D": [5,5,5,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=foo)

mask1 = df["D"] > 1  # True for rows 0,1,2
mask2 = df["B"] % 2 == 0 # True for row 1
mask3 = df["A"] == df["B"]  # True for rows 0,1,2
```

However, in this case, I'd like to match rows for which *n* or more such expressions are true. In the above example, I'd like rows that match at least 2 of the criteria. I realize of course that this can be achieved by something like (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND 3) OR (2 AND 3), but that quickly becomes untractable to write and I was wondering if a more elegant solution exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `concat` the results and do a `sum`:

```
print (pd.concat([mask1,mask2,mask3],1).sum(1)>=2)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score -1):

How about (mask1+mask2+mask3>=2) ?

Comment: Summing them just gives another boolean, so this does not solve the problem at all. It would be helpful if you didn't post suggestions that may or may not work as answers. That results in the question not appearing under unanswered questions anymore.